# How colSpan and row Span added to material table Header Angular 16?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular16, tableheader

I'm trying to add **`rowSpan and colSpan`** in **`Angular material Table header`**. Can anyone help me to achieve  it.

Below is the Attached Header I want to get using material table

[image]

Answer (score 28):

I have the sample task like you. I just easy to display none with second header.

```html
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}"> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

 <!-- first stage header -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="No">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">No</th>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is my result
[image: Table row span]

You can follow my link to know more:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-jgvsiq?file=app/table-basic-example.html)

Comment: I have been looking to combine fixed column effect with colSpan. This helped a lot. However it only works with the older <table mat-table> tag not <mat-table> tag.

Comment: I saw it also working with tag <mat-table>. Using mat-table it's not make sense with me.

Comment: for simple hard-coded stuff like `[attr.rowspan]="2"`, you can get away with just a simpler `rowspan="2"`, since it's static, and doesn't need to be dynamic 

Comment: The same thing goes for the styling `style="display:none;"` will work fine for your hidden cell 
as well. 

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same issue and, using some inspiration from previous answers, found the following to work perfectly.

To achieve the example provided in the question, you will need two table headers. The first will contain the `State`, `Utilities company` and `Summer Period` columns, while the second will contain the `data1`, `data2` & `data3` columns. To do this, start with the following:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="my-table">
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['state', 'company', 'summer']"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['data1', 'data2', 'data3']"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['state', 'company', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3']"></tr>
</table>
```

This piece of code creates a table with two table header rows and, for each data point in your dataSource, one row with 5 cells which use the columns provided.

To properly style these header rows, we need to use `rowSpan` and `colSpan`. For each column, we create our `ng-container`:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="state">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">State</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">State name here (e.g. {{data.state}})</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="company">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">Utilities company</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">Utilities company here</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="summer">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="3">Summer</th>
  <!-- This column doesn't generate <td> items, so no need to add a definition for them -->
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="data1">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Data 1</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{data.yourFirstDataPoint}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="data2">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Data 2</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{data.yourSecondDataPoint}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="data3">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Data 3</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{data.yourThirdDataPoint}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

This creates the desired result for you. If you want, you can add `mat-sort` definitions to your columns, as well. I hope this makes sense, if not, let me know and I'll try to expand my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For your exemple try this

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef rowspan="2">state</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" >alabama</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="utility">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef rowspan="2">utility company</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" >company1</td>
</ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="data1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{'data1' | translate}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" >3.45</td>      
 </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="data2">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{'data2' | translate}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" >1.73</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="data3">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{'data3' | translate}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" >0.58</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="summer">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef colspan="3">{{'summer period' | translate}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let company;let i = dataIndex" ></td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-row *matHeaderRowDef="['state','utility','data1','data2','data3']"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matHeaderRowDef="['summer']"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns:['state','utility','data1','data2','data3']"></tr>
</table>
```

I just reverse the order of the summer row because seem to not work this way

Answer (score 0):

I just used `[attr.colspan]` and `[attr.rowspan]` on my material table

```
<table mat-table> 
 <ng-container matColumnDef="{{displayedColumns[0]}}">
    <th
      mat-header-cell
      class="text-center"
      *matHeaderCellDef>          
    </th>
    <td
      mat-cell
      class="text accent text-center"
      *matCellDef="let item">
    </td>
    <!-- usage example -->
    <td
      [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length"
      mat-footer-cell
      *matFooterCellDef>
    </td>
 </ng-container>
        .............
 <tbody>
   <tr
     mat-header-row
     class="mat-table-row-sm header-accent-separator"
     *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
   <tr
     mat-row
     class="mat-table-row-sm"
     *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   <tr
     mat-footer-row
     class="mat-table-row-sm position-relative"
     *matFooterRowDef="[displayedColumns[0]]; sticky: true">
    <!-- matFooterRowDef can be the count of columns -->
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use native-table features such as colspan and rowspan you will need to use:

```
<table mat-table>

  ...

</table>
```

Ref: [Native table element tags](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-code-display-flex-code-)

For example:

[image]

Ref: [Serendipity CRM](https://github.com/Robinyo/serendipity)