# How to use rowspan and colspan in angular6 with material design

Tags: angular, angular-material

> Can someone help how to design angular 6 with a material table header
>   using colspan and rowspan like this image? which is give below -

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440755/2358409

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment above, the basic approach for solving this problem is explained in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440755/2358409.

Based on this, I've created a StackBlitz with imaginary data, which shows a solution for your particular case.

Please have a look at [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-hjvasf?file=app/table-basic-example.html)