# How to make group header in a table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Does anyone have a small example on Angular Material of how to implement a group header as shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another question about this problem , [How colSpan and row Span added to material table Header Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55701270/6052427)

This feature name table with irregular headers you can learn more detail about it.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

This solution will be work on your project

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-jgvsiq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Finally web site exampe here : )

https://github.com/hxling/ng-xui/tree/master/src/app/Demos/Datagrid/header-group

Comment: I have seen that. This is not at all like the one implemented in the screenshot.

Comment: Could you please share this web site link with me ?