# How to use footer with colspan to align total in mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

Need to show the total below the amount column.

Currently, I'm using the `margin-left` property to show the total below the amount column. Since this is not working properly, could someone suggest to me how to achieve this using a table footer with colspan?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-design-mxj3ho?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How colSpan and row Span added to material table Header Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701270/how-colspan-and-row-span-added-to-material-table-header-angular-7)

Comment: @Wandrille I need this total should be displayed at the end of the table also I think the table footer needs to be used here.

Comment: Just read the official docs on the `mat-footer-row` [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#footer-row). They even provide an working example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-footer-row).

Comment: @TotallyNewb thanks for the document I can able to do it https://stackblitz.com/edit/kp2rjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You need the `mat-footer-row` as mentioned in the comment.

1. Add this line:

```
<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
```

after `<tr mat-row>` element.

2. Make sure each element contains `matColumnDef` attribute must have:

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
```

3. For `Amount` element, the `mat-footer-cell` should be:

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total: {{ getTotal() }} </td>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-design-q7fjz8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks. i can able to do it https://stackblitz.com/edit/kp2rjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it using `mat-footer-row`

Below need to add for each column

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
```

For amount column

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{getTotalCost() | currency}}</td>
```

below needs to be added

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kp2rjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.html)